# Is "system.threading.channels" will solve the pub sub problem for cross process applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.threading.channels

I have a asp.net core application "A" which generates files every 1 minute in a folder.

Application "B" wants a notification or file details what file we generated and some Hash information for that file. Based on this notification, Application "B" wants to process the files.

I am thinking of some pub/sub mechanism and I want very light weight components where Application "A" will publish the file related information and Application "B" will subscribe and listen.

Is "system.threading.channels" will solve this problem?

Comment: What you describe doesn't seem to have anything to do with pub/sub.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that sounds very much like pub/sub to me... nothing to do with "channels", though

Comment: Thanks. That's my thoughts. Without pub/sub what are the ways?

Comment: I need some pub/sub with zero installation, if possible.

Comment: @MarcGravell it's inter-process communication through a shared folder. Yes, it's a publisher/subscriber problem, in the same way bikes and lorries are wheeled vehicles though. No in-process mechanism can work with the current question

Comment: @user584018 you're using `pub/sub` as if it is a specific library or technology. It's not, it's a very broad problem description that could even cover sending .... paper ballots. For starters, you can use a FileSystemWatcher to check when a new file is created. A better approach may be to have one application call the other's HTTP endpoint and send the entire file.

Comment: Are the two applications running on the same machine? Or on the same local network?

Comment: both applications running in same machine, both are dotnet core applications

Comment: I would consider a file-based communication, which is low tech and easy to monitor. The application A would create two files each time, the main file and an `.info` file containing metadata about the main file. The application B would set a `FileSystemWatcher` observing the folder, with a filter for `.info` files. It would open each new `.info` file, would read the metadata, and then process the main file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short version: no.

`System.Threading.Channels` is in-process - very similar to `Queue<T>` in many ways, but designed for `async` access; no part of that API allows IPC.

There are a number of ways of doing this cross-process (and potentially cross-machine), but the options that leap to mind would be:

- have one of the nodes set up a socket server, and have the other node connect over sockets; send messages to each-other that way
- the same, but with named pipes instead of sockets
- the same, but with an http server; kestrel is pretty easy to setup as a server
- using an external message broker or pipe as the intermediary, and have both nodes connect to that as clients
- just detect changes to the file system